# Не подключается шрифт в темплейте

Tags: html, css, gmail, google-fonts, mandrill

Через [mandrill](http://ttps://mandrillapp.com) ведется рассылка почты.
Там же, в самом начале документа подключается шрифт `Open Sans`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 " />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
...
```

а в ячейках стили такие

```
<td  width="55" align="left" valign="top" class="em_w1" style="font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:17px; color:#3f2957; font-weight:600;">
    Item #                                        
</td>
```

В итоге отображается шрифт `Arial`.
Есть у кого идеи, как это можно пофиксить?

Answer (score 3):

Причины этому две:

1. Почтовые клиенты не поддерживают `@font-face`, а шрифты в css подключаются только так. Поддержка есть только в клиентах OS X и iOS ([исследование](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/03/does-font-face-work-in-email/));
2. Почтовые клиенты в большинстве своем не поддерживают стили из внешних файлов, а некоторые не поддерживают стили и в `<style>`, только инлайновые.

Рекомендую вам отказаться от кастомных шрифтов в письмах, и для текста использовать стандартные. В крайнем случае заголовки вы можете оформить картинками.